# Directive doesn't work within different files

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I'm currently having an issue with `@Directive`s and `@Hostlistener`s and I would love your help

I don't know why when I add the directive to the input it doesn't do anything, it doesn't fire any event, not even a `console.log()` and I'm desperate right now, because there must be something I'm missing, but I don't now what.

I have the following project structure.

```
app
|
|___ components
|   |
|   |___ Autocomplete
|       |___ autcomplete.component.html
|       |___ autcomplete.component.ts
|       |___ autcomplete.component.css
|
|
|___ directives
|   |___ keyboard.directive.ts
|
|___ app.module.ts
```

In `autocomplete.component.html`:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label [attr.for]="id">{{ label }}</label>
    <input keyboard type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputData" 
           name="inputData" [attr.id]="id"
           class="autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
```

and `keyboard.directive.ts`:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[keyboard]'
})

export class KeyboardDirective {

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event']) onFocus(value: string) {
        console.log('Focus caught.');
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyPressed(e: any) {
        console.log('keydown event);
    }
}
```

and my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import {KeyboardDirective} from '../app/directives/keyboard.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        KeyboardDirective
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

I tried adding it to the component itself and it works, but it doesn't when is in other folder, so I would thank any hint on why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have the full code, I'll list your possible mistakes :

1 - In the module where you declare your Autocomplete component, you should import the directive. I don't see your component being declared anywhere.

2 - If the directive isn't in the same module, then you need to import the module where you declared your directive. Since you declared it in appModule, I would advise you to create another module for your directives.

3 - in the directives modules, you need to export the directives. Otherwise, you will get an error saying the directive/component is unknown.

If you could try that and update your post, that would be good !

Comment: Hi! and thanks for your help, but should I declare/import the directive in the component if it's imported and declared into app.module.ts?

Comment: I guess you forgot the rest of your message ?

Comment: Yes, sorry... enter issue.

Also... by exporting you mean the line -> export class KeyboardDirective in keyboard.directive.ts

Comment: First question : no, you should declare your directive in a new module, called `DirectivesModule` or `SharedModule`, that you can then import in another modules (for instance, in AppModule). For the second question, I mean you need to add an exports property in your decorator. This means, under your `declarations: [KeyboardDirective]`, you must add `exports: [KeyboardDirective]`

Comment: Hi again! Thank you very much for your hints, they were really helpful. 
I solved the problem I was declaring/exporting the directive in the wrong place. I was doing it at app level but not on the component ngModule itself.

Comment: That's what I thought at first. Glad I could help you !